# Footer is not fixing

Tags: css, internet-explorer, windows-phone-7

I was testing my mobile application, with Windows mobile.I got some issues with the footer part.The problem is regarding footer fixing. When I scroll the contents, the footer also getting up.But the footer is fixed in all browsers including IE and in all mobiles except windows version.

See the code, for IE I gave,

```
* html #footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

Edit:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrapper {min-height: 100%;}


#footer {
    position:fixed; z-index:999;
    width:100%;
    bottom:-20px;
    margin-top: -72px; /* negative value of footer height */
    margin-top: 0px !ie; /* for IE */
    height: 92px;
    clear:both; text-align:center;
    background:url(../../) repeat-x #115c9c;
    }
```

Comment: Does mobile IE even support expressions? I would recommend avoiding them. Tried a javascript solution instead?

Comment: Don't use CSS hacks, negative margins, etc. This stuff makes everything worse, not better. Try design as easy and simple layout and CSS rules as possible. Try to discover which CSS rules are not supported on which devices.

Comment: @Bli_n: I didn't quite understood your question. For the `position:absolute` property; "it should be positioned relative to its first positioned ancestor element".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 – both pre and post-Mango ignore fixed positioning and render fixed elements as position: static. IE9 desktop and other browsers you tested on supports position: fixed. 
http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

Expressions seems no more supported
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/10/16/ending-expressions.aspx

So I would recommend to remove 'position: fixed' and make it working in IE9 desktop first since there is no easy way to debug html in WP7. It also seems you will have to proceed with additional js to get fixed footer in WP7.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for fixing footer:

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  Website Header
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>
    A Solution for fixing footer section on webpage. it works every where even with mobile application too.
    blah....blah...blah....blah...blah....blah.... blah....blah... ... blah....blah.... ....blah....blah ...blah....blah ....blah....blah .... blah....blah..... blah....blah... blah....blah...blah....blah..!! 
  </p>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  Fixed Footer is copyright&copy;2012
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header{
  width:90%;
  height:15%;
  background-color:#152087;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  color:#a7a575;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:5px;
  margin:0px;
}
.content{
  margin:0px;
  font-size:16px;
  height:70%;
  overflow:scroll;
}
.footer{
  position:fixed;

  z-index:999;
  width:90%;
  clear:both;

  text-align:center;
  height: 50px;
  bottom:-20px;
  margin-top: -72px;
  /* value of footer height */
  margin-top: 0px !IE;
  /* for IE */
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:#152087;
  color:#a7a575;
  font-size:14px;


}
```

I have also tested on bins, so click on http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpbv

Comment: What if the header height needs to be set in pixels, not percentage?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery mobile add this  to your css

```
.ui-page .ui-footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into whether or not the windows mobile browser supports fixed positioning. You might have to write some javascript that checks how far down the page is scrolled and place the footer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change viewport width for all 3 resolutions available in windows phone 8

below code will work for HTC windows phone 8x

Include meta tag in your head section.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
```

Include below style in your head section

```
<style>
    @media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
        @-ms-viewport { width: 50%; }        
    }
</style
```

You need to write this for all 3 resolution available for windows phone 8. You might have to decrease width for higher DPI phones and increase width for lesser DPI phone.

viewport width for Nokia lumia 920 will be around 70-80% and for Nokia Lumia 820 it would be around 85-95%. But you need to find out min width and max width for both these phones.

Comment: This does not help to fixate CSS elements on WP8 web apps.